# 2 Dimensional Knapscak algorithm

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, approximation, np-hard

I am trying to get the algorithm(close to optimal) for a variant of 2 dimensional knapsack problem, below is the problem description.

lets say we have n number of rectangle R1(l1,w1)

R2(l2,w2)......Rn(ln,wn) and each with associated cost (cl1,cw1) (cl2,cw2).....(cln,cwn).So for each rectangle cost for length(or could be per unit) is cli and cost for width(or per unit) is cwi. Now we have given m user rectangle r1,r2,...rm and we need to place them in the R1..Rn such that cost required to put is minimum.
priority wise constraints-

1- We need to place maximum number of user reactangles(if possible put all)

2- Minimize the cost(price will be charged based on area covered in R1..Rn)

Comment: Can more than one user rectangle ri fit into a single given rectangle Rj?

Comment: @AriHietanen. sure

Comment: CCan you rotate rectangles?  If so, what happens to cost?

Comment: @stark, No rotaion is not permitted for any kind of rectangle

Comment: Then start by filling from lowest to highest cost R.  Use simulated annealing to perturb the arrangement and settle on the best solution.